# How to plot a 3d surface graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, geometry-surface

I have a dataset like so:

```
  | 0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
----------------------
1 | 10   11   12   13
2 | 11   12   13   14
3 | 12   13   14   15
4 | 13   14   15   16
```

I want to plot a 3D surface graph in matlab such that the column headings will be on the y axis, the row headings will be on the x axis and the remaining values will determine the height of the point on the z axis.

I have had a look around at lots of different example and I can't work out how to achieve this. At the moment I have got the following:

```
Y = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4];
X = [1 2 3 4];
Z = [10 11 12 13; 11 12 13 14; 12 13 14 15; 13 14 15 16];
```

Please could someone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't realise it was so simple - I was massively overcomplicating my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

May a bar plot yield the desired picture?

```
Y = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4];
X = [1 2 3 4];
Z = [10 11 12 13; 11 12 13 14; 12 13 14 15; 13 14 15 16];

figure;
bar3(Z)
set(gca(gcf), 'xticklabel',{'0.1','0.2','0.3','0.4'})
```

[image: 3d plot]

Comment: Hello, thank you for this response. Do you are sure that your answer is true? If yes, so I can use it :)