# Understanding 3D surface plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

As in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281442/how-to-plot-a-3d-surface-graph-in-matlab), I have:

```
      | 0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
    ----------------------
    1 | 10   11   12   13
    2 | 11   12   13   14
    3 | 12   13   14   15
    4 | 13   14   15   16

    Y = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4];
    X = [1 2 3 4];
    Z = [10 11 12 13; 11 12 13 14; 12 13 14 15; 13 14 15 16];
```

I plotted the surface Z using the command "surf(X,Y,Z)" in matlab. I got:

[image]

But really I don't understand the plotted surface. Can someone explain to me in details (in a text) what happens in this surface? For example: how can we observe the point (2,0.2,12)?

Comment: To identify individual points you could plot them in the picture. Maybe try: *hold on; plot3(2,0.2,12,'ro')*.  Additional you could add labels to the plot:  *xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z')*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include some labels and a colorbar and everything should be clear:

```
Y = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4];
X = [1 2 3 4];
Z = [10 11 12 13; 11 12 13 14; 12 13 14 15; 13 14 15 16];

surf(X,Y,Z)
colorbar
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
```

As suggested in the comments you can find your point on the surface by adding:

```
hold on;
plot3(2,0.2,12,'ro','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','r');
```

it then appears as a red dot.

[image]

Your table contains 16 points, these are plotted and the area inbetween, colored according to the applied colormap with the lowest z-value of the group of 4, which is according to the [**doc**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) the **surface height**.

Actually it would be cleaner coding if you'd include the following line before the plot:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(X,Y);
```

this way all your input variables get the same dimensions:

```
X =
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4

Y =
          0.1          0.1          0.1          0.1
          0.2          0.2          0.2          0.2
          0.3          0.3          0.3          0.3
          0.4          0.4          0.4          0.4

Z =
    10    11    12    13
    11    12    13    14
    12    13    14    15
    13    14    15    16
```

In case of `surf` the function does that for you, but other plotting functions are may not that tolerant.

Comment: yes, I included it, the color is determined by the "surface height" which is the lowest or bottom value.

Comment: But why you choose plot3(2, 0.2, 12, 'ro'). Why not other one ?

Comment: because you requested it?

Comment: If I would like to plot 2 points. ? In other words, to observe 2 ot more points on the surface

Comment: @Christina copy the line and insert other coordinates.

Comment: jajaja of course, But I got only the point of the second plot

Comment: you haven't forgot `hold on`? it isn't hidden behind the surface?